# How to create population proportion boundaries?

Tags: maps, qgis, population

> [Essentially what im trying to recreate.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MqNCJ.png)

I'm looking to create a map like this for chicago, except including the most recent decades as well. In qgis, how can I create approximate boundaries, like in the above image, that includes 2/3 (or another proportion) of people in northern illinois.

Any help would be much appreciated!

After loading the data, I'm struggling to create a function that would make a boundary like this.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.